# Jboss-deployment-structure.xml can't see class from other deployment.myear.ear.etc

Tags: jboss

I try to migrate from jboss 4.2.3 to jboss 7.0.2. When i try to deploy my ear file below :

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dts.jar
dts.sar
dts.war
itext-2.1.2.jar
itext-rtf-2.1.2.jar
jboss-el-1.0_02.CR3.jar
jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar
jboss-seam-excel-2.2.0.GA.jar
jboss-seam-jul-2.2.0.GA.jar
jboss-seam-mail-2.2.0.GA.jar
jboss-seam-pdf-2.2.0.GA.jar
jboss-seam-ui-2.2.0.GA.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jxl-2.6.8-seam.jar
loginHook-hook.war
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
portal-client-6.1.0.jar
quartz-1.8.4.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
util-bridges-6.1.0.jar
util-java-6.1.0.jar
util-taglib-6.1.0.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
xstream-1.1.3.jar
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-ear/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-ear/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-ear/pom.properties
```

I get this error:

```
13:17:57,562 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."dts.ear"."dts.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."dts.ear"."dts.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "dts.war" of deployment "dts.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.recglobal.dts.chart.SalesGoalChartServlet
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleClassDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(EEModuleClassDescription.java:176)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEClassConfigurationProcessor$1.compute(EEClassConfigurationProcessor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:40)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEApplicationDescription.getClassConfiguration(EEApplicationDescription.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription.createConfiguration(ComponentDescription.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartGenerateVariables
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [:1.6.0_15]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.recglobal.dts.chart.ChartGenerateVariables from [Module "deployment.dts.ear.dts.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [:1.6.0_15]
    ... 18 more
```

Couse of error is this, when deploying dts.war, dts.war need a method from dts.jar(below):

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/recglobal/
com/recglobal/dts/
com/recglobal/dts/chart/AnnualChart.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartGenerateVariables.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartGenerator$1.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartGenerator.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/ChartType.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/QuarterlyChart.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/RangeUtil.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/Timescale.class
com/recglobal/dts/chart/XYBarAlarmRenderer.class
components.properties
dts-app-features.xml
features.xsd
META-INF/persistence.xml
seam.properties
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-logic/
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-logic/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.recglobal.dts/dts-logic/pom.properties
```

So to solve this problem i edit Jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my dts.ear to that:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>   
   <module name="deployment.dts.ear.dts.jar" />
   <module name="deployment.dts.ear.dts.war" />
    </dependencies>
    <resources>
    </resources>
    </deployment>
   <sub-deployment name="dts.war">
        <dependencies>           
            <module name="deployment.dts.ear.d2ts.jar" />
        </dependencies>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="deployment.dts.ear.dts.jar.com.recglobal.dts.chart.ChartGenerateVariables"/>
        </resources>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I try a lot of combinations founds on forums and google but everything ends with this same error. Also try to edit MANIFEST.MF but nothing works. General i don't know what to do when ClassLoader can't find class or JAR File. Class Loader can't even find jars in dts.war in WEB-INF/lib(sick!) i must moved them to the EAR and mark in dts.war.pom.xml as provided But now i already try deploy dts.jar from EAR and even with false dts.war still can't see my logic jar(dts.jar). I really need help with this couse I am running out of ideas.U can't ask me about whatevere u need. So help me maybe pls :)

Comment: Hi, did you come to any solution with this classloading problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add "Dependencies: missing jar" ?

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html